# HTML5 History API popstate reload safari refreshes page endlessly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history

I fonud safari refreshes the page endlessly when I hit the "back" button with this code

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

Chrome and IE are fine. How can this issue be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
location.reload(true);
```

should work for Safari)
[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload)

Comment: Thanks, but still the same

Comment: same problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

this hack is working for me :/

https://gist.github.com/voku/854fef3b9a3fbf10624f

```js
/**
 * reload on history-back with "history.pushState" usage
 *
 * Necessary hack because WebKit fires a popstate event on document load
 * https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040
 * https://bugs.webkit.org/process_bug.cgi
 */
$(window).bind('load', function() {
  if (Modernizr.history) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
        location.reload();
      });
    }, 0);
  }
});
```